# django download generated file

Tags: python, django, download, httpresponse

Download a generated file (.xlsx). This is a snippet from a view. 
Are better solutions than this?

```
inventory_file = open(file_path, "rb")
response = HttpResponse(inventory_file, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
return response
```

Comment: For which definition of "better" ?

Comment: code performance, code optimization, code correctness ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should send the file as a chunk , which is memory efficient

```
import os
import mimetypes
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper


def download_file(request):
   the_file = open(file_path, "rb")
   filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
   chunk_size = 8192
   response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(the_file, 'rb'), chunk_size),
                           content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0])
   response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(the_file)    
   response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
   return response
```